# Pandas: Filling data for missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

Let's say I've got the following table:

```
ProdID  Date        Val1 Val2 Val3
Prod1   4/1/2019    1    3    4
Prod1   4/3/2019    2    3    54
Prod1   4/4/2019    3    4    54
Prod2   4/1/2019    1    3    3
Prod2   4/2/2019    1    3    4
Prod2   4/3/2019    2    4    4
Prod2   4/4/2019    2    5    3
```

`Prod2` entries are populated correctly as we've got the data from `4/1/2019` to `4/4/2019`.

`Prod1` has 1 missing date - `4/2/2019`.

I would like to find missing dates for all ProdIDs and fill in Val1-3 with data copied from the last of previous entry. For instance, I would like to copy data from `4/1/2019` to `4/2/2019`

```
ProdID  Date        Val1 Val2 Val3
Prod1   4/1/2019    1    3    4
Prod1   4/2/2019    1    3    4
Prod1   4/3/2019    2    3    54
Prod1   4/4/2019    3    4    54
Prod2   4/1/2019    1    3    3
Prod2   4/2/2019    1    3    4
Prod2   4/3/2019    2    4    4
Prod2   4/4/2019    2    5    3
```

Answer (score 6):

First convert column to `datetime`s by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then create `DatetimeIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and call [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) - there is also possible specify method for forward or back filling missing values:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = (df.set_index('Date')
         .groupby('ProdID')
         .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D', method='ffill'))
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))

print (df1)
  ProdID       Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0  Prod1 2019-04-01     1     3     4
1  Prod1 2019-04-02     1     3     4
2  Prod1 2019-04-03     2     3    54
3  Prod1 2019-04-04     3     4    54
4  Prod2 2019-04-01     1     3     3
5  Prod2 2019-04-02     1     3     4
6  Prod2 2019-04-03     2     4     4
7  Prod2 2019-04-04     2     5     3
```

Another solution is create all combinations of product and `datetimes` by [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, last forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].min(), end=df['Date'].max())
prods = df.ProdID.unique()

from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(prods, dates)), columns=['ProdID', 'Date'])
print (df1)
  ProdID       Date
0  Prod1 2019-04-01
1  Prod1 2019-04-02
2  Prod1 2019-04-03
3  Prod1 2019-04-04
4  Prod2 2019-04-01
5  Prod2 2019-04-02
6  Prod2 2019-04-03
7  Prod2 2019-04-04

df = df1.merge(df, how='left').ffill()
print (df)
  ProdID       Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0  Prod1 2019-04-01   1.0   3.0   4.0
1  Prod1 2019-04-02   1.0   3.0   4.0
2  Prod1 2019-04-03   2.0   3.0  54.0
3  Prod1 2019-04-04   3.0   4.0  54.0
4  Prod2 2019-04-01   1.0   3.0   3.0
5  Prod2 2019-04-02   1.0   3.0   4.0
6  Prod2 2019-04-03   2.0   4.0   4.0
7  Prod2 2019-04-04   2.0   5.0   3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It returned the following error: "ValueError: NaTType does not support time"

Comment: @MarekK - What is your pandas version?

Comment: version: 0.23.4

Comment: @MarekK - working for another solution, give em a sec.

Comment: @MarekK - Added another solution with `merge`, please check it.

Comment: I know where the problem is. Looks like I've got inconsistent date formats in input csv files. I need to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
dates = pd.date_range(start=df.Date.min(), end=df.Date.max(), freq='1D')

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.ProdID.unique(), dates], names=['ProdID', 'Date'])

df.set_index(['ProdID', 'Date']).reindex(idx).ffill().reset_index()
```

[output]

```
  ProdID       Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0  Prod1 2019-04-01   1.0   3.0   4.0
1  Prod1 2019-04-02   1.0   3.0   4.0
2  Prod1 2019-04-03   2.0   3.0  54.0
3  Prod1 2019-04-04   3.0   4.0  54.0
4  Prod2 2019-04-01   1.0   3.0   3.0
5  Prod2 2019-04-02   1.0   3.0   4.0
6  Prod2 2019-04-03   2.0   4.0   4.0
7  Prod2 2019-04-04   2.0   5.0   3.0
```